# open new page in model popup with jquery

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog

Any one have idea how to open a new page in model popup using jQuery.
New page should be Aspx page. 
I do not want use ajax extender.

Comment: Did you mean modal? Like a jQuery UI modal dialog?

Comment: i want to say that new page like country.aspx should be open as a model window

Comment: Hmm, if you're not referring to a _modal_, can you explain what a _model_ window is?

Comment: @Rusty *I* could explain what a model window is, but several restraining orders and stubborn judges have hindered my research.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

```
$('#dialog').load('/path/to/aspx', function() {
    $(this).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 200
    });
});
```

This will [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) the page at `/path/to/aspx` in a div with id `dialog` and then present the contents of the div in a modal window.

Include the following in your html

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

See the [linked documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for more information.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.but iam a new in jquery.can you tell how to implement this

Comment: here how can open new aspx page?

Comment: I've added an example. You'll have to combine jQuery load with UI Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of jQuery UI Dialog, you could use the [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/) Plugin.
It's a very cool plugin and easy to use. Here a simple step by step instruction:

1. Put all the required links into the head part of your webpage, it's explained on their webpage.
2. Than you'll have to add this piece of code somewhere on your Webpage, best in the head:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
   })
   ```
3. If you did this, you can just insert HTML links like this:

   ```
   <a href="somepage.aspx" rel="facebox">Link Title</a>
   ```

I hope that helps you.